# how to install my printer

Tags: printing

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu on an Aspire 2920 and now find my printer isn't working. I know I probably need to install it again but I don't see the 'printer' section in 'hardware' in the system
settings. I would be grateful for some help.

Thank you

Comment: What printer do you have?